# Matplotlib figure as SVG with Shiny for Python

Tags: python, py-shiny

The axis labels and titles in the figure in the app below appears unsharp to me. I assume it's because the figure is rendered as PNG, so I assume that rendering it as SVG will fix the issue. However, I'm not sure how to do that. Any pointers?

```
from shiny import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.output_plot("dens_plot"),
    ui.input_slider(id = "n", label = "slider", min = 10, max = 50, value = 10)
)

def server(input, output, session):
    @output
    @render.plot
    def dens_plot():
        xs = list(range(input.n()+1))
        ys = [1]*len(xs)
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.stem(xs, ys , markerfmt = " ")
        ax.set_xlabel("X title")
        ax.set_ylabel("Y title")
        return fig

app = App(app_ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `render.plot` uses base64 for PNG always, [here is the proof](https://github.com/rstudio/py-shiny/blob/011f93587d35d0bc1200ebdc9395ef4b925650dc/shiny/render/_try_render_plot.py#L149). However, I have an idea to use the `render.image` with SVG created on the level of pure python code (`plt.figsave`). Please refer to the attached example app where in the web DOM you will find out the base64 based on SVG.

[Please refer to this simple pyshiny app](https://shinylive.io/py/editor/#code=NobwRAdghgtgpmAXGKAHVA6VBPMAaMAYwHsIAXOcpMAMwCdiYACAZwAsBLCbJjmVYnTJMAVAB0IfAUKYwoZVABtiZRRwBGWbEpVMoLJkrISJaVAH0ArhyYBeJtaxQA5nHM1F1gCYAKCUwCHDgxiSwUw8x0yPzAvShZI5WMwAEo8f0DHLlQIljU4uh8OLzsmMUhyvCZFKHU4RVLyvOK4OkrZLlKARgAGKrkAD1KAVj6mADcoTzhunpSJeYgJOJpWVvHWoogcsirQ8N21lhYOUhTEDICAAX2dy6YrukoCjD4XOHuVpjiIBKifc73QK8fiCYQUfg0DiKD4QYHAmheKqoeRsUoQ1BQmEYGAAaxYGJ8LEsNChQ3sAHIMCxxs4KYt4YEBgZ7GoCT46FAIK4tjsMBAAQBqLopBmMpjYFlMYBdAC6IhhAuZYsZUOcVSg5MMijI1Ms6iiLABQMCmupEJ8zKqkqY-SgdFxrRoMGE9nKZVSJoCZpYcDI5gGNTqihiAA0mGQOKoPp64eKfX7zNgg-UYgBNCNRmHlFXwtXUqAbNU+FFkNi54FPMiWOhwkBNOiEcqIVhkQql8tVcoAd2KZebHoAbD0eqgBu1yjRBHJkhcwDTnOUAL4mOOM1dmUoAQXQPjMVg4VV9dA2dBSYCXsqAA)

Comment: That's a clever workaround. Thanks!